# (React) Can't show data in component properly

Tags: reactjs

I have been struggling to retrieve data and show them in the component correctly. It seems that I can retrieve data from backend. But when it comes to render it to the component, that's when the error comes in, saying that attractions.map is not a function.

[Console Result Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhNFv.png)

The Following is my code:

```
export function ShowAttraction(props:RouteComponentProps<{tripId:string,scheduleItemId:string}>){

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const attractions = useSelector((state:IRootState)=> state.attraction.attractions);
    console.log(attractions)
    const isClick = useSelector((state:IRootState)=> state.attraction.isClick);

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(getAllAttractionsThunk());
        dispatch(getAllScheduleItemsThunk());
    },[dispatch])

    const renderAttractions=(i:number,key:string,attraction:IAttraction,isClick:boolean)=>{
        return <MediaCard
            attraction={attraction}
            key={key}
            value={"+"}
            attractionOnClick={()=>handleClick(i)}
            isClick={isClick} />
    }


    const handleClick=(i:number)=>{
        isClick ? deleteScheduleItemThunk(parseInt(props.match.params.scheduleItemId)) 
                : createScheduleItemThunk();
    }

    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="attraction-area">
                {attractions.map(attraction =>(
                    <div className="attraction-row" key={`attraction_${attraction.id}`}>
                        {
                            renderAttractions(
                                attraction.id,
                                `$attraction_${attraction.id}`,attraction,false
                            )
                        }
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the upper part of the console show that the `attractions` is a object with the attributes `rows` which contain the actual arrays. 
You could probably try the following

```
<div className="attraction-area">
                {attractions.rows.map(attraction =>(
                    <div className="attraction-row" key={`attraction_${attraction.id}`}>
                        {
                            renderAttractions(
                                attraction.id,
                                `$attraction_${attraction.id}`,attraction,false
                            )
                        }
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
```

Of course it probably also means your backend is returning the object that is different from your expectation.